# How make a Light Wall Glow

Tags: lighting

[image: halo]

How can I make that halo effect on a wall?

Answer (score 4):

add a text, convert to mesh, add 2 materials -> upper side red with some noise, lower side -> blue with strong emission

Materials:

[image]

[image]

Cycles render

**Compositing with glare**

[image]

result:

[image]

[image]